# Efficiently loop over CSV file and validate against very large database tables in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm working on a project where I upload a CSV file then I loop through each row, and enumerate over each value in the row. If the field has an entry I need to validate it against a large table of values.

How I handle this at the moment is I do a single query from each table I need, the primary keys. So, I will pull in 300k primary keys and validate against that list. This is much quicker than hitting the database with a single .get request each and every time.

My question is - can this be done more efficiently?

Example of my code:

```
large1_list = list(large1.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True))
large2_list = list(large2.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True))

csv_file = request.FILES['csv_file']
csv_parsed = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(csv_file, 'utf-8'), delimiter=',')

for fields in csv:
    for i, x in enumerate(fields):
        if i == 0:
            if x not in large1_list:
                   return blah blah blah
```

And so on. I'm thinking there has to be a more efficient way to do this... But I figure this is better than actually hitting a DB each and every time.